# Search Specific Keyword From a File and add description associated to it to different file with Python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

Below text file shows the Description of Channel Name & the Channel Event

***desc.txt file:***

```
Channel Name: CBS
Event Name: FIFA World Cup 2018 Qualifying

Channel Name: BEINSPORTS
Event Name: NFL
```

Below Python code only looks for the First "Event Name" and associated description.

```
flist = open('/tmp/desc.txt').readlines()
    for line in flist:
        if line.startswith("Event Name:"):
            eventname = line[12:-1]                  
            file2 = open('/tmp/test_live.txt','w')
            file2.write(eventname + "\n")
```

What I want is the below description and what I am getting currently is 
"FIFA World Cup 2018 Qualifying" in the file.

***test_live.txt***

```
FIFA World Cup 2018 Qualifying
NFL
```

Comment: your indentation is wrong  check your `for` loop. Is that correct code? it seems fine to me.

Comment: also you can use `eventname = line[12:]` that should be suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You keep opening the same file and writing one line to it. You have two options: You can either open it once outside the loop (more efficient), and close it when exiting the loop (you should close your other `open` statement too). Or you can open it with `'a'` instead of `'w'` to *append* to the file.
But I would just open it before going into the `for` loop. 
Also your loop should not be indented under the `flist` line unless you use `with`...

Note: I think typically you should use `.rstrip()` instead of truncating the `\n` with `[:-1]` The last line might not have a newline at the end, and you would lose that character.

```
with open('/tmp/desc.txt') as flist:
    file2 = open('/tmp/test_live.txt','w')
    for line in flist:
        if line.startswith("Event Name:"):
            eventname = line[12:-1]                  
            file2.write(eventname + "\n")
    file2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you're opening the file in write (`'w'`) mode so the entire content of the file test_live.txt is wiped with every iteration. Use append (`'a'`) mode instead.

Answer (score 0):

What the previous posts indicated with the implemented code.

```
flist = open('/tmp/desc.txt', 'r').readlines()
file2 = open('/tmp/test_live.txt','a')
for line in flist:
    if line.startswith("Event Name:"):
        eventname = line[12:-1]                  
        file2.write(eventname + "\n")
#Close Open File handlers
flist.close()
file2.close()
```